# Visual Studio Version Selector mistakenly thinks visual studio 2010 is installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way I can tell Visual Studio Version Selector to never select 2010?

The only Visual Studio I have installed on my computer is 2013.  When I try to open up a 2010 solution file by double clicking on it, Visual Studio mistakenly thinks I have 2010 installed and tries to open it with that.  This gives me the following error: "Invalid license data. Reinstall is required." With an image saying Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell.

My current work around for opening 2010 solutions is to right click and select Open With, make sure I uncheck the option "use this app with all .sln files", then find Visual Studio 2013 and select that.

I have never directly installed Visual Studio 2010, but I suspect some other installations installed parts of it for them to work.  On the same date I got the Visual Studio 2010 Shell installed I happened to install Sql Server 2014 as well as one other product developed by the company I work for.

When I go to Add/Remove Programs I have the following installed (with their installed On date)

`Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 (11/6/2014)
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)  (11/6/2014)
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU (12/12/2014)
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.60610 (11/6/2014)
    Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.60610 (11/6/2014)
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Runtime - 10.0.40219 (12/12/2014)
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable - 10.0.40219 (12/12/2014)
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219 (12/12/2014)
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219 (12/12/2014)`

I am currently using Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Comment: I had the same issue, and I suspected it was the Visual Studio 2010 Shell. I uninstalled it, and that removed VS2010 from the Visual Studio Version Selector, and double-clicking a VS2010 project opens my VS2013. HOWEVER, Visual Studio 2010 Shell was installed by SQL 2014 Express and without it, SQL Management Studio would not launch. So I had to re-install Visual Studio 2010 Shell. And I just live with the work-around you said: right-click a VS2010 solution and open with VS2013.

Comment: Ah, dammit... this is friggin annoying. I'm also stuck with having to use the silly workaround (also can't do without SSMS).